# Unable to log in (authetication error) after a series of package management operations

Tags: login, authentication

I tried to install Photoshop on Ubuntu, but I did not get it, so I have several times removed and installed packages PlayOnLinux, Wine, also I accidentally deleted the package X.Org (mixed with xterm). After I moved away from the computer for a while, it went into sleep mode, I tried to get it out of there, but it gave me an error(pictured) and then crashed.

After the reboot, the Ubuntu graphical shell stopped running. I went to recovery and reinstalled X.Org. The graphical shell worked, but the old error remained: when I try to log in, the computer first issues an authorization error for a second(the photo shows the inscription in Russian) and then issues a black screen with lines of system code.

[image: Login Screen]

This is the screen I'm getting

[image: System logs]

How do I get my system back up and running?

Comment: Have you installed only X.Org? Since I don't know Russian, is it really saying authorization error? Or is it something like "Unable to start session"? Please open recovery mode again and run `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: @Kulfy It’s an authentication error according to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ru&tl=en&text=%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: try changing your user's password by booting into root Shell prompt in recovery mode.

[This Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/24024/1001175) details how to do it.